# Rails 5 - How do I prevent Rails from adding locale to a URL on constructed paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading to Rails 5.2, (edit: using `"5.2.0.rc1"`) I now have `?locale=en` being added to my urls when I use a path constructed from `path_helper` (like `login_path`). How do I stop Rails from adding the locale to my urls? I don't need them, ever.

#### My controller:

```
    #home_controller.rb

```
def index
    redirect_to login_path
end
```

```

#### Application.rb

```

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    config.generators do |g|
       g.fixture_replacement :rspec
       g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot
    end
  end
end
```

```

#### What Happens:

It redirects me to `localhost:3000/login?locale=en`

Comment: What does your application.rb filre look like?

Comment: added to question

Comment: Is this all that's in the file? I'm looking for something as shown here. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-i18n
Do you have anything like that? Especially something like `config.i18n.default_locale`

Comment: Yeah, that's all thats in the file :/

Comment: I'm sensing it's something with the `path_helper` in this version of rails - when I hardcode the redirect as string`"/login"`, it's all good. but when I use `login_path` it adds the locale

Comment: Hmm.... well the only thing I can think of right now is to check these files. First, the `home_controller.rb`. Look for any `before_action` methods that may deal with that. Next the `application_controller.rb` file. After that try the `config/routes.rb` file. You may have something in `routes.rb` that is appending the locale.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somewhere along the line in Rails 5 the `path_helper` regressed to no longer omit optional params like locale when constructing URLs. Only thing to do is wait for a PR to fix it. Looks like a lot have been made but unclear if they have been merged or if the fix exists in `5.2.1`

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32526

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32382

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33846